# how to create website thumb nail using PHP?

Tags: php, thumbnails

I do have a code with me couple of years back to create a website thumbnail using PHP in windows. But I cant find the same now is there anybody has a code to generate same on Windows?? or some Ideas to capture a website preview??

Comment: Why not use something like Websnapr to just grab your sample image and forgo all the PHP code?

Comment: Is your question mark key stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try checking out this PHP class. It's one of the only ones I know that does this sort of thing.

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4608-PHP-Take-screenshots-of-pages-with-Internet-Explorer.html

Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

if working on  windows hosting use

(http://www.zubrag.com/scripts/website-thumbnail-generator.php.)

Note( it only works with windows hosting). It does not work with linux hosting.The reason

behind this is the php iamge function(imagegrab) only works with windows Environment

->third party API service Provider  which are very much efficient and very easy to use

1. http://www.bitpixels.com/
2. http://pagepeeker.com/