# thumbnail-web-screenshots-script with PHP

Tags: php, thumbnails

Is there anyway to create website screenshot thumbnails on the fly via a PHP script?

Comment: Duplicate of [PHP or JS Website Thumbnail Script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453028/php-or-js-website-thumbnail-script) and [many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=website+screenshot)

Answer (score 2):

take a look at for example

- [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)
- [how to create website thumb nail using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629587/how-to-create-website-thumb-nail-using-php)

or many other here on stackoverflow

Comment: that was nothing - just some research ;), can you mark it right then ;)